# Assign variables to random elements from list? Python

Tags: python, arrays, list

I wan an array which is going to have about 30 things in it. Each thing in the array is going to be a set of variables, and depending on which thing in the array is chosen, different variables will be set.

e.g.

```
foo = ['fish', 'mammal', 'bird']
ranfoo = random.randint(0,2)
animal = foo[ranfoo]
```

this works fine for returning a random element from the list, but how then, depending on the item selected do I assign some variables to them?.

e.g. 'bird' has been randomly selected, I want to assign : flight = yes swim =  no. Or something along those lines... What I'm programming is a little more complicated but that's basically it. I've tried this:

```
def thing(fish):
    flight = no
    swim = yes

def thing(mammal):
    flight = no
    swim = yes

def thing(bird):
    flight = yes
    swim = no

foo = ['fish', 'mammal', 'bird']
ranfoo = random.randint(0,2)
animal = foo[ranfoo]

thing(animal)
```

But that doesn't work either and I don't know what else to do... Help???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about making a `thing` class?

```
class thing:
  def __init__(self, type = ''):
    self.type = type

    self.flight = (self.type in ['bird'])
    self.swim = (self.type in ['fish', 'mammal'])
```

Now, it's quite simple to choose a random "thing":

```
import random

things = ['fish', 'mammal', 'bird']
randomThing = thing(random.sample(things,  1))

print randomThing.type
print randomThing.flight
print randomThing.swim
```

---

So you are making a multiple-choice thing?

Maybe this would work:

```
class Question:
  def __init__(self, question = '', choices = [], correct = None, answer = None):
    self.question = question
    self.choices = choices
    self.correct = correct

  def answer(self, answer):
    self.answer = answer

  def grade(self):
    return self.answer == self.correct

class Test:
  def __init__(self, questions):
    self.questions = questions

  def result(self):
    return sum([question.grade() for question in self.questions])

  def total(self):
    return len(self.questions)

  def percentage(self):
    return 100.0 * float(self.result()) / float(self.total())
```

So a sample test would be like this:

```
questions = [Question('What is 0 + 0?', [0, 1, 2, 3], 0),
             Question('What is 1 + 1?', [0, 1, 2, 3], 2)]

test = Test(questions)

test.questions[0].answer(3) # Answers with the fourth item in answers, not three.
test.questions[1].answer(2)

print test.percentage()
# Prints 50.0
```

Comment: But in the one I am coding it's not just wether is swims or not, It is a list of random questions with multiple choice answers... how would I impliment the different answers into this?

Comment: @Blender This is great, thank-you so much! But how would I let the person choose the answer?

Comment: `print the_question.choices` to show answers, and do a `raw_input()` to catch user input.

Comment: @Blender Hasn't worked. I says syntax error and highlights 'the_question'

Comment: I meant do that to a question object, where `the_question` is the question ;) Try `print test.questions[0].choices`.

Comment: I have tried a variety of methods to define 'answer' as the players input() but it never works. The test percentage always comes up as 0.0. I have managed to get the question to print etc but I can't catch the users input.

Comment: Do you cast the answer to an `int`? Like `int(raw_input('? '))`? And also, read the source. It compares the answer *number*, not the answer itself...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check what animal is with an if statement:

```
if animal == 'bird':
    flight = yes
    swim = no
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing strings in the string, store an object that inherits from a common animal base class, then you can do:

```
class animal:
    def thing(self):
          raise NotImplementedError( "Should have implemented this" )     

class fish(animal):
    def thing(self):
        """ do something with the fish """
       self.flight = yes
       self.swim = no


foo = [aFish, aMammal, aBird]
ranfoo = random.randint(0,2)
animal = foo[ranfoo]
animal.thing()
```

Answer (score 0):

An extension of @Blender's answer:

```
class Thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, flies=False, swims=False):
        self.name  = name
        self.flies = flies
        self.swims = swims

foo = [
    Thing('fish', swims=True),
    Thing('bat', flies=True),
    Thing('bird', flies=True)
]
```